# Ошибка при сортировке массива типа double

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, сравнение, double

В моём распоряжении функция для сортировки массивов различного типа и массив типа double. Написал две функции для сравнения и перемены местами значений массива. Но при выполнении программы числа с одинаковой экспонентой не сортируются. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка.

функция сортировки

```
void Sort
(
    char* pcFirst,              // указатель на первый сортируемый элемент 
    int nNumber,                // количество сортируемых элементов
    int size,                   // размер элемента в байтах
    void(*Swap)(void*, void*),  // указатель на функцию перестановки элементов
    int(*Compare)(void*, void*) // указатель на функцию сравнения элементов
)
{
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < nNumber; i++)
        
            for (int j = nNumber - 1; j >= i; j--)
            {
                char* pCurrent = pcFirst + (j * size);    //указатель на текущий элемент
                char* pPrevious = pcFirst + (j - 1)*size; //указатель на предыдущий элемент

                if ((*Compare)(pPrevious, pCurrent) > 0) // если возращаемое значение >0 то требуется переставить
                {                                   
                    (*Swap)(pPrevious, pCurrent); // меняем местами
                }
            }
}
```

функция сравнения

```
int CmpDouble(void* p1, void* p2)
{
    
    int nResult;
    double discrepancy = 1e-7;
    

    if ((abs(*(static_cast<double*>(p1)) < discrepancy)) < ((abs (*(static_cast<double*>(p2))) < discrepancy)))
    {
        nResult = (*(static_cast<double*>(p1)) -*(static_cast<double*>(p2)));
    }
    else if ((abs(*(static_cast<double*>(p1)) < discrepancy)) == ((abs(*(static_cast<double*>(p2))) < discrepancy)))
    {
        nResult = (*(static_cast<double*>(p1)) - *(static_cast<double*>(p2)));
    }
    else if ((abs(*(static_cast<double*>(p1)) < discrepancy)) > ((abs(*(static_cast<double*>(p2))) < discrepancy)))
    {
        nResult = (*(static_cast<double*>(p1)) - *(static_cast<double*>(p2)));
    }

    return nResult;
}
```

функция перестановки

```
void SwapDouble(void* p1, void* p2) 
{
    double tmp;
    tmp = *(static_cast<double*>(p1));
    *(static_cast<double*>(p1)) = *(static_cast<double*>(p2));
    *(static_cast<double*>(p2)) = tmp;
}
```

Comment: У вас самого в глазах от этих static_cast и дурацких угловых скобочек в глазах не рябит? Можно ведь написать просто `double *p1d = (double *)p1, *p2d = (double *)p2;` и далее работать с `p1d` и `p2d`

Comment: Пример с входными данными? Зачем в функции `CmpDouble` преобразуете разность двух `double`в `int`? Потеря дробной части при таком преобразовании и возможное переполнение вас не беспокоят? См.: `int(0.5 - 0.4) == int(0.1) == 0`.

Comment: В возвращаемом значении точность не нужна. Тут главное больше нуля или нет.

Comment: Вообще, напишите русскими словами, как именно вы хотите сравнивать эти 2 double? Я правильно понимаю, что если они разлачаются меньше чем на `1e-7`, то надо считать их равными?

Comment: Ну, не нужна точность, так не нужна. Например, все числа из множества `{-0.4, -0.3, 0.3, 0.4}` ваш компаратор считает попарно равными. В чём тогда вопрос?

Comment: Наоборот. Если если они различаются меньше чем на 1e-7, то надо считать их разными.

Comment: Хотя наверно Вы правы. От discrepancy нужно избавляться.  Но при этом результат остается тем же. А по поводу возвращаемого значения. Оно на вывод массива ни какого влияния не оказывает. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Ещё раз: в функции сравнения для определения порядка вы находите разность двух чисел с плавающей точкой, затем эту разность приводите к типу `int`. Это приводит к потере дробной части, что напрямую влияет на порядок сортировки. Например, все числа из множества `{-0.4, -0.3, 0.3, 0.4}` функция сравнения [считает равными](https://ideone.com/zPRRZR). Так и задумано? Опишите словами как должна работать функция сравнения. Если особых требований нет, то почему бы не определять порядок чисел с помощью операторов `<` и `>`? Примерно [так](https://ideone.com/7tMTzp).

Comment: Порядок работы программы 1. Изначальна задана функция сортировки массива. Её менять нельзя. 2.Произвольно задается массив типа double { 2.2, 2.1, 4, -1, 11.2, 8.6}.  3. Необходимо написать две функции. Функция CmpDouble принимает два void указателя. Сравнивает их и если p1>p2, то  и говорит, что значение больше нуля и вызывает функцию перестановки  SwapDouble. После чего благополучно выводит на консоль.

Comment: Характерно то, что все символы сортируются нормально. Но когда идут 2.1, 2,5, 2,2 то они не сортируются, а выводятся так как и заданы.

Comment: Wololo. Спасибо!!!!! Всё заработало как нужно. Вот этот код #включить <iostream>
#включить <cmath>
#включить <cstdlib>
 
int CmpDouble( постоянная пустота* p1,  постоянная пустота* p2)
{
 double a = *static_cast<const double*>(p1);
 double b = *static_cast<const double*>(p2);
 
 bool a_nan = std::isnan(a);
 bool b_nan = std::isnan(b);
 
 если (a_nan || b_nan)
 {
  вернуть b_nan - a_nan;
 }
 
 верните a < b ? -1 : a >> b ? 1 : 0;
}

Comment: Всё просто и изящно. Спасибо!!!!!

Comment: Wololo. я могу выложить Ваш код в качестве ответа на свой вопрос?